# Jenkins not showing jobs after restart

Tags: java, jenkins, automation

I kill jenkins process and started again. After the restart, all the jobs are disappeard. However in my jenkins directory under "jobs" I can see all the job folder still exist.

```
/app/jenkins
```

Look like somehow I need to tell the jenkins to pickup all the configuration from existing directory. But not sure how to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you create new job does it create at the same location ?

Comment: Actually it was my mistake. Somehow environment variable JENKINS_HOME hasn't been set up. That was the reason it didn't pickup the old jobs. Thanks anyways.. :)

Comment: you can answer your own question for other's refernece

Comment: I was thinking on deleting the question but yea that's better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a mistake on my part. The reason Jenkins didn't pick up the old jobs is that upon restart, I did not have my `JENKINS_HOME` environment variable defined. Thus Jenkins didn't pick up the old jobs.

```
 export JENKINS_HOME=/app/jenkins
```